# Multilingual site and issues with homepage on GSC

Tags: google-search-console, bing-webmaster-tools, yandex-webmaster-tools

I have a challenge here: my client has the homepage for each location added to the main website property and not in the URL prefix profiles for any locations.

What I mean is...

GSC as usual, has a website property profile like

- website.com

And for the specific location URL prefix as subfolder like:

- website.com/en-ca/ or /en-au/ and so on.

Now what happens is that the homepage URL is like this:

The homepage for each location is like this: [www.website.com/en-ca](http://www.website.com/en-ca)

- **Without the last slash.**

This means that the homepage is only visible to the main GSC website property and not in the URL prefix profiles subfolder as website.com/en-ca/

Leaving without any data related to the homepage for any specific URL prefix profile in GSC.

I need help finding something related to this topic if this is a good practice or not. Or how google reads the homepage or what URL Google identifies as a homepage from specific multilingual sites. Will this be a hidden penalty by google?

I'm recommending changing every homepage, like: website.com/en-ca/home

Same in Bing or Yandex.

Note:

- The status 200 for website.com/en-ca
- Status 301 for website.com/en-ca/
- Redirection set is 301 from website.com/en-ca/ to website.com/en-ca

Answer (score 1):

***First part of your answer:***

The use of the last slash is completely optional. What you do have to take care is to **only use 1 version**. Either with or without, but don't respond to both.

In your example:

- website.com/en-ca <= should return a **200** code
- website.com/en-ca/ <= should return a **301** redirection code to website.com/en-ca

***Second part of your answer:***

In the case of multilingual sites, you have to properly setup **hreflang tags**. You must define a main "default" language, and refer to every other language in which your website shows info. An example header to guide you:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="https://example.com/en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://example.com/en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://example.com/fr" />
```

It's easy to make a mistake here. I recommend, once you configure your headers, run them through an online **hreflang tags testing tool**. There are many out there that can help you to diagnose any problems.

Comment: Thx @Luis It has indeed all that set, as you mention. However, the issue is with GSC.
The homepage doesn't show any data on the **URL prefix as subfolder profile** in GSC, the data only show on the **website property** profile. The URL prefix profile provides data only after the last **/** website.com/en-ca/ not without

Comment: Also, I double-check multiple times, our redirection is 301 from website.com/en-ca/ to website.com/en-ca

Comment: Please provide your site's URL for me to take a look into it

Comment: From the lack of engagement on this forum, I had no choice but to use google support webmaster, have a look on their answers:


https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/225607706?hl=en&sjid=639232964216577461-EU